# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string error while assigning numbers to days of the week

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am doing a assignment for school in Sql and I have run into trouble. I have to create a user function where when you enter a date, you will receive back the number of the day of the week (Monday being 1, Tuesday 2 etc). I the code I managed to write is below, however i am getting

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string error"

so i guess i need to do some casting. I have researched around but so far I have found only datetime hints as how to convert and thus far, I was unable to implement in my code.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[whichDay] (@p_day [datetime])
RETURNS [int]
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @selectedDate [int]
SET @selectedDate= CASE 
  WHEN @p_day IN (N'Monday') THEN 1   
  WHEN @p_day IN (N'Tuesday') THEN 2  
  WHEN DAY (@p_day) IN (N'Wednesday') THEN 3    
  WHEN DAY (@p_day) IN (N'Thursday') THEN 4    
  WHEN DAY (@p_day) IN (N'Friday') THEN 5    
  WHEN DAY (@p_day) IN (N'Saturday') THEN 6
  ELSE 7 
END
RETURN @selectedDate

END;
GO
```

I have tried also this with IF statements (IF then ELSE IF for all other days) but I couldn't figure out that one as well.

Comment: @TabAlleman May I ask why did you remove `sql-server` tag? I know that OP wrote `I am doing a assignment for school in MySql` but his example clearly indicates that it is T-SQL language(SQL Server/Sybase).

Comment: I gave more weight to the first sentence than to the code.   It seemed more likely to me that OP would post faulty code in a question than that he would say he's specifically using MySQL when he's not.

Comment: Yes, I expressed myself wrong. Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it looks like `SQL Server` (`GO`, quoting with `[]`) not `MySQL`.

Your code does not work because you cannot compare `DATE` with invalid date literal.

```
WHEN @p_day IN (N'Monday') THEN 1   
-- here you compares some date with 'Monday'
-- DATETIME has higher precedence than string so SQL Server tries to
-- implicitly cast to DATETIME

<=>
SELECT @p_day = CAST('Monday' AS DATETIME)
-- Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

To get day of the week you could use built-in [`DATEPART`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx):

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;      -- set first day of week to `Monday` default for US is Sunday
-- this could be set as global or connection based
DECLARE @p_day [datetime] = GETDATE();

SELECT DATEPART(dw, @p_day);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/443870)**</kbd>

---

If you are using `MySQL` you could use [`DAYOFWEEK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek):

> Returns the weekday index for date (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 = Saturday). These index values correspond to the ODBC standard.

```
SELECT IF(DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1=0, 7,DAYOFWEEK(NOW())-1);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/47311/0)**</kbd>

## Addendum

One more thing comparing directly with weekday name won't work when language is different that `en`.

[DATENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx):

> **The return value depends on the language environment** set by using SET LANGUAGE and by the Configure the default language Server Configuration Option of the login

Consider:

```
SET LANGUAGE russian;
SELECT DATENAME(dw,GETDATE());
-- среда
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/444120)**</kbd>

Then using code as you proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35735514/5070879 will always return 7.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you lad2025 for your input. It helped me realize where was the problem. I adjusted the code and now it works as intended. Besides your advice, I looked over some notes that I had from class and used a different method for solving the problem. I believe that this can be done with less lines of code, however, it performs the desired function. You can see the correct code below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[kojiJeDan] (@p_day [datetime])

RETURNS [int]

AS 

BEGIN

DECLARE @selectedDate [int]
SET  @selectedDate= CASE (SELECT DATENAME(dw, @p_day))
WHEN N'Monday' THEN 1 
WHEN N'Tuesday' THEN 2
WHEN N'Wednesday' THEN 3
WHEN N'Thursday' THEN 4
WHEN N'Friday' THEN 5
WHEN N'Saturday' THEN 6
ELSE 7 
END
RETURN @selectedDate
END;

GO
```

Comment: You should note that `DATENAME` is language dependent. See my edit.